# SAS - The internal source spool file has been truncated - YHQSRC/XZPWRIT failure

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've found failure message log unknown for me. There is simple macro-code which works correctly for a long time.

What does it mean?

```
NOTE: The internal source spool file has been truncated. Error logging with line and column information may be incomplete until 
      next step boundary.
YHQSRC/XZPWRIT failure
```

SAS 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a `NOTE` not `ERROR`. There is a SAS support note about this:

[Usage Note 7275: "Internal source spool file has been truncated" error messages appear when reading large amounts of data](http://support.sas.com/techsup/notes/v8/7/275.html)

Also I found this on support. Hope it helps.

> Please consider the following options to get rid of this note:
>
> - option NOSPOOL creates smaller spool file (30% smaller).
> - UTILLOC directs the spool file away from WORK.
> - point WORK to a larger file system
> - split up  your code.

Comment: Does there is a cause with no free space on server hasrd disk? What do you think about it?

Comment: It could be that you drive/mount point where you have `WORK` library is full during macro execution. Maybe try setting `OPTIONS NOSPOOL;` and cleaning unused data during macro execution.